# couldn't import django:importError

Tags: python, django, anaconda

I am working on a Django project and at the beginning everything was going well . But for say 2 days i'm not more able to run my project using the `Python run manage.py`  it gives me this error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 17, in 
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment ?**

I use Anaconda as virtual environment . During my debugging process I checked the installed packages in the environment , and this is the output.

[image: th]

I also use python 3.8 as interpreter but outside the virtual environment.

Comment: check that the interpreter  is pointed to conda env directory

Comment: @CYREX Thanks for your response . I tried your suggestion and that actually works . 

Comment: Happy to help :-) iam gonna post it as answer. upvote & check to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the interpreter is pointed to conda env directory.